# Set a Price Display Suffix for user role

Tags: woocommerce, roles, suffix

I would like a different price suffix for two different user roles on my WooC site.

The **general customer** will have no suffix and price including tax, which I have set in Woo settings Tax tab.

The **Trade customer** has price ex tax and I want to give it the suffix "ex VAT ({price_including_tax} inc VAT)".

An alternative I could do is to set the Woo settings with this suffix, and instead try to hide the suffix from the general customer and other user roles. However I'd prefer to add it, and have tried the code below which I found and modified, but it doesn't work.

Could anyone suggest what is wrong with it?

```
add_filter( 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 ); 
function custom_price_suffix($price, $current_user_role) { 
$your_suffix = 'ex VAT ({price_including_tax} inc VAT)'; 
if($current_user_role == 'default_wholesaler') { 
$price .= '$your_suffix '; } 

return apply_filters( 'custom_price_suffix', $your_suffix ); 

}
```

Thanks to the suggestion below.  I currently have the following code:

```
function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    $your_suffix = 'ex VAT ({price_including_tax} inc VAT)';

    // check current user role
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;

    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $roles ) ) {
        $price = $your_suffix;
    } elseif ( in_array( 'default_wholesaler', $roles ) ) {
        $price = 'ex VAT ({price_including_tax} inc VAT)';
    }

    // return $price;
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
```

The result of this code is the suffix now only appears once. However it has removed the price from showing, and it still doesnt recognise the {price_including_tax} shortcode.

[As displays for default-wholesaler user on front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jexoq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following `wp_get_current_user()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/

```php
function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    // for debug purposes, delete after testing
    echo '1 = ' . $price;

    $your_suffix = 'suffix here';

    // check current user role
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;

    // for debug purposes, delete after testing
    echo '<pre>2 = ' , print_r($roles, 1), '</pre>';

    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $roles ) ) {
        $price = $price . ' - ' . $your_suffix;
    } elseif ( in_array( 'user...', $roles ) ) {
        $price = 'something';
    }

    // return $price;
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that!  Unfortunately it isnt quite working.  In the product I get the suffix appearing twice, and it also doesnt recognise the Woo shortcode {price_including_tax}

Comment: the shortcode should be used with WordPress Dashboard> WooCommerce> Settings> Tax> Tax Options> “Price display suffix”?

Comment: Hi, yes it is a shortcode that would usually be placed there. However as most of my store doesn't need a suffix, just for the user role.  So, I think at this time there are two options: is there a way to have it recognise this shortcode in this code?  Or I need to add the shortcode in the settings, and instead hide it from all users except the 'Default_wholesaler' user. I dont know what is easier!

Comment: then you should not add the suffix to the price ( $price .= ....) because that is a string but overwrite ( $price = ....). (without the point for the equal sign) 
I have adjusted my code, look at the result and adjust where necessary

Comment: "Or I need to add the shortcode in the settings, and instead hide it from all users except the 'Default_wholesaler' user" -> 
yes, that is an option

Comment: Hi again, just tried your new code, and edited my post to show the exact code I put in (amended from yours - I am not a coder so I might have modified it wrong) and the latest results I am getting from it!  Thanks so much for your help so far - any other ideas?  I think we're close!

Comment: the {price_including_tax} placeholder is for use in the backend (as I indicated earlier),  
just going to copy / paste into the code will not work because it is not recognized

Comment: ok, thanks for your help!  I will start a new topic to try the alternative, and put the suffix in the backend and remove the suffix for other users!